# Protocols get - set | I couldn't set new value

Tags: swift, protocols, url-parameters

I cannot add a new value to the dictionary. I can't see the value I added in the URL.
I'm trying to add the `genres` parameter.

I assign `genders` to `parameters` in `GameListRequestModel`, but I can't see it in the URL, why?

**URL on Postman:**

`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=6b4fab3e88ecfake2c15379&genres=4`

**URL on Xcode Console:**

There is no `genres`.

`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=6b4fab3e88ec48aab19933b2c153c7c9`

**Requestable Protocol:**

```
protocol Requestable {
    var baseURL: String? { get }
    var paths : [String]? { get }
    var parameters : [String : Any]? { get set }
    var headers : [String : String]? { get }
    var method : RequestMethod? { get }
    var body : [String : Any]? { get }
    
    func generateRequest() -> URLRequest?
    mutating func prepareRequest()
}

extension Requestable {
    
    var baseURL: String? {
        return ApiConstant.baseUrl.rawValue
    }
    var method: RequestMethod? {
        return .get
    }
    var body: [String : Any]? {
        return nil
    }
    var parameters: [String: Any]? {
        get {
            return [
                "key": "6b4fab3e88ec48aab19933b2c153c7c9"
            ]
        } set { } //genres ?
    }
    var headers: [String : String]? {
        return nil
    }
    
    mutating func prepareRequest() { }
}
```

**GameListRequestModel:**

```
struct GameListRequestModel: Requestable {
    var paths: [String]?
    
    private var genres: Int? = nil
    
    init(paths: [String], genres: Int? = nil) {
        self.paths = paths
        self.genres = genres
        prepareRequest()
    }
    
    mutating func prepareRequest() {
        guard let genres = genres
        else { return }
        let stringGenres = String(genres)
        self.parameters = [
            "genres": stringGenres
        ]
        print("foo parameters: \(self.parameters)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, no. I see what you are trying to do here, but you cannot add default implementations of stored properties in a protocol extension like that.

Comment: Should I delete the protocol and make a class and override properties ?